# Mysql Key Partition on uuid

Tags: mysql, key, partitioning

While partitioning table into 4 partitions using key partitions on an uuid, all the data is getting stored in p0, p2 and no data is getting stored in p1 and p3.

Comment: Not too surprising as not the entire value of the uuid changes with insertions on the same server. Your ranges are probably too wide.

Comment: So @Shadow what can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: What do you usually need to do, if something is too wide?

Comment: I am dumping data for already generated 0.1 million uuids and data is getting populated in p0 and p2 only. By range do mean increase the number of entries? @Shadow
The uuids are generated in a random way only. Are there any mysql/code related solutions I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `PARTITION BY HASH`, which is lame in that way.

Probably no partition would be of any use for a UUID key.

Please provide the `SELECTs` (etc) that you think might benefit from Partitioning.  I will (probably) explain why Partition won't help in that case.